# Google test results html is different from view source html

Tags: seo, html, search

When I see page html in google test rich results I see SearchAction and WebSite attributes in Rendered Html and there is an error about it.

'SearchAction' object must be nested inside a 'WebSite' object

But these itemprop markups are not assigned in the code and it is not in View Source. Why do I see them in google test rich results and how I can change them?

Site uses clickio - can it be connected?

Thank you!

Comment: What technology do you use? Do you use a client side rendering one?

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've tested Javascript-injected structured data in Google's structured data tools, and found the tools are able to pick them up.

It sounds like the tool you're using is picking up Javascript injected elements, and when you view the source on your own you're seeing the HTML prior to the Javascript firing.

Instead of viewing source (control+U) try inspecting element (control+I) and that will show you the state of the HTML after Javascript execution.